# subprocces.call Syntax Error python

Tags: python, openssl, subprocess, syntax-error

Attempting to run a command using python with `subprocess.call` but I’m getting a syntax error

```
#Takes cipher and password, executes openssl command in console
def decrypt(cipher, password):
    try:
        print 'Attempting decryption --->   Cipher: ' +cipher+ '    Password: ' + password
        call(['openssl', 'enc', '-d', cipher, '/media/"username"/Data Drive/Documents/Project mangement/forensics/images/19_1.enc','-out', 'decrypted.dat' '-k', password])

    except Error as e:
        print e
```

---

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/media/"username"/Data Drive/Downloads/bruteforce(2).py", line 9, in <module>
  import call
File "/home/"username"/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/call/__init__.py", line 37
class _PythonCall(metaclass=ABCMeta):
                           ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It would appear that whatever is being imported by `import call` has a syntax error in it that's most likely not at all related to the code you've posted... `call` is not one of the standard library modules, so I have no idea what it is... Unless it's supposed to be `from subprocess import call` or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:
from subprocess import call

Instead of:
Import call

Answer (score 0):

metaclass is a Python 3 idiom. So the file `"/home/"username"/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/call/__init__.py"` is from a Python 3 bundle. Yet it is installed in a Python 2 tree. Something must be seriously wrong in the way you installed Python.